# C++ ошибка компиляции. ld returned 1 exit status. gcc

Tags: c++, c, windows

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `AppWindow::AppWindow()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `Window::init()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd4): undefined reference to `Window::isRun()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `Window::broadcast()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `AppWindow::~AppWindow()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `AppWindow::~AppWindow()'
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRMYmsr.o:main.cpp:(.xdata+0x44): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Код **main.cpp**:

```cpp
#include "AppWindow.h"

int main()
{
    AppWindow app;
    if (app.init())
    {
        while (app.isRun())
        {
            app.broadcast();
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Код **Window.cpp**:

```
#include "Window.h"

//Window* window=nullptr;

Window::Window()
{
    
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    //GetWindowLong(hwnd,)
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // Event fired when the window is created
        // collected here..
        Window* window = (Window*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lparam)->lpCreateParams;
        // .. and then stored for later lookup
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)window);
        window->onCreate();
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        // Event fired when the window is destroyed
        Window* window =(Window*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
        window->onDestroy();
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }


    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return NULL;
}


bool Window::init()
{


    //Setting up WNDCLASSEX object
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hInstance = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "MyWindowClass";
    wc.lpszMenuName = "";
    wc.style = NULL;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;

    if (!::RegisterClassEx(&wc)) // If the registration of class will fail, the function will return false
        return false;

    /*if (!window)
        window = this;*/

    //Creation of the window
    m_hwnd=::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "MyWindowClass", "DirectX Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1024, 768,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, this);

    //if the creation fail return false
    if (!m_hwnd) 
        return false;

    //show up the window
    ::ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    ::UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);


    

    //set this flag to true to indicate that the window is initialized and running
    m_is_run = true;



    return true;
}

bool Window::broadcast()
{
    MSG msg;

    
    while (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    this->onUpdate();

    Sleep(1);

    return true;
}


bool Window::release()
{
    //Destroy the window
    if (!::DestroyWindow(m_hwnd))
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool Window::isRun()
{
    return m_is_run;
}

void Window::onCreate()
{
}

void Window::onUpdate()
{
}

void Window::onDestroy()
{
    m_is_run = false;
}

Window::~Window()
{
}
```

Код **AppWindow.cpp**:

```
#include "AppWindow.h"



AppWindow::AppWindow()
{
}


AppWindow::~AppWindow()
{
}

void AppWindow::onCreate()
{
    Window::onCreate();

}

void AppWindow::onUpdate()
{
    Window::onUpdate();

}

void AppWindow::onDestroy()
{
    Window::onDestroy();
}
```

Код **AppWindow.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "Window.h"


class AppWindow: public Window {
    public:
        AppWindow();
        ~AppWindow();

        virtual void onCreate() override;
        virtual void onDestroy() override;
        virtual void onUpdate() override;
};
```

Код **Window.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

class Window
{
public:
    Window();
    //Initialize the window
    bool init();
    bool broadcast();
    //Release the window
    bool release();
    bool isRun();

    //EVENTS
    virtual void onCreate();
    virtual void onUpdate();
    virtual void onDestroy();


    ~Window();
protected:
    HWND m_hwnd;
    bool m_is_run;
};
```

Comment: Нужно указать все .cpp-файлы через пробел, не только `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g++ main.cpp Window.cpp AppWindow.cpp -o main.exe

Comment: Попробую проверить.